# Плавность при scroll'е

Tags: javascript, прокрутка

Здравствуйте.

Есть маленький код, который устанавливает значение `top` у блока в зависимости от положения scroll'а. Проблема в том, что не во всех браузерах оно плавно отображается, т.е. при scroll'е происходят резкие скачки (браузера: *IE*, *Opera <11* и т.д.). Как убрать эти скачки и сделать полностью плавные движения?

Код:

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
 document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].style.marginTop = window.pageYOffset + 'px';
};
```

```css
body {height: 2000px; }
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Отображение со скачками:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На картинке маленькие скачки, но с разными объектами и разными браузерами - скачки разного размера.

Ссылка на сторонний редактор: [jsfiddle-gjx7ecd4](https://jsfiddle.net/yuri_spivak/gjx7ecd4/)

Comment: А нужно именно через `margin`?

Comment: @SLy_huh, тут не важно. Оно и с `position: absolute; top...px` дёргается

Comment: Ну в том плане, что поведение блока сильно похожа на `fixed`, с тем исключением, что он при полной прокрутке вверх, он маргинится на несколько пикселей. Мб, при скролле на `2+px` ему просто класс присваивать с `position: fixed; top:0;`?

Comment: @SLy_huh, можно. Но думал можно как-то скриптово убрать эти скоки-прыги. Добавьте свой вариант и я его приму :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поведение блока сильно похоже на fixed, с тем исключением, что при полной прокрутке окна вверх, он маргинится на несколько пикселей. Возможно, решением будет - присвоение ему класса с необходимыми параметрами, если величина прокрутки окна больше его первоначального отступа.

```js
var elem = document.getElementById('test'); //получаем целевой элемент
var style = elem.currentStyle || window.getComputedStyle(elem);/* тк, если
напрямую обратиться к свойству style,
то мы получим список правил для, непосредственно, ЭЛЕМЕНТА,
нам же нужен именно список правил, 
для таблицы стилей(первое выражение для IE)*/
var scrollOffset = style.marginTop;//Собственно, получаем начальный отступ из стилей
scrollOffset = scrollOffset.substr(0, scrollOffset.length-2)//убираем злосчастные `px`
window.onscroll = function() {
  if(window.pageYOffset > scrollOffset){
     elem.className = 'scrolled';
    return;
  }
  elem.className = '';
};
```

```css
body {height: 2000px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;}
div#test {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: black;
  margin-top: 7px;
}
.scrolled{
  position: fixed;
  margin-top: 0px !important;
  /*Свойства стилей для id перекрывают свойства для классов,
 посему так, но для новичков: это BAD PRACTICE!*/
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: red !important;
  /*Просто, дабы понимать, что сейчас на нем висит класс*/
}
```

```html
<div id='test'></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Никакими ухищрениями сделать плавный скролл через onscroll не получится. Проблема в том, что за время поворота колеса мыши вылетает 5-12 событий onwheel, которые трансформируются в onscroll. Ваш код пытается их переварить - и получаются скачки.

Событие scroll не всплывает, поэтому стандартный scroll невозможно отменить через preventDefault.

Возился с этой проблемой довольно долго. Пришлось перехватывать onWheel и анимировать плавно до нужного места. Анимацию делал на jQuery, здесь в рамках ответа на javascript анимацию не ставил - просто скроллинг окна и `transfrom: translate`.

Важное замечание. Браузер по-разному обрабатывает `top` и `transform`, есть примеры в Сети, что `transform` работает намного более плавно.

Приведенный ниже код перехватывает onWheel, накапливает события в течение 150мс, чтобы отследить полное единичное движение колеса, затем поднимает флажок `animating`. Во время "анимации" скрипт не воспринимает более никакие новые события скролла, один раз прокручивает окно на полную ранее просуммированную величину скролла, изменяет положение черного квадрата через `transform` и через 100мс сбрасывает флажок `animating`.

Эти величины - 150 и 100мс - сугубо эмпирические и подгоняются под конкретную задачу, особенно в том случае, если скрипт осуществляет анимацию элемента.

```
//    Так квадрат дергается

//    window.onscroll = function() {
//        document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].style.transform = 'translateY(' + window.pageYOffset + 'px' + ')';
//        return false;
//    };

//  А так - не дергается

var animating = false;
var timeoutID;

function onWheel(event) {
    event = event || window.event;
    var pos = event.deltaY || event.detail || event.wheelDelta;
    console.log(pos);
    if (animating) {
        finalPos = finalPos + pos;
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
    if (pos > 0) {
        // downscroll code
        if (!animating) {
            // Scroll
            animating = true;
            finalPos = pos;
            event.preventDefault();
            clearTimeout(timeoutID);
            timeoutID = setTimeout(function() {
                console.log('scroll to ' + finalPos);
                window.scrollTo(window.scrollX, window.scrollY + finalPos);
                document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].style.transform = 'translateY(' + window.pageYOffset + 'px' + ')';
                setTimeout(function() {
                    animating = false;
                }, 100);
            }, 150);
        }
    } else {
        // upscroll code
        if (!animating) {
            // Scroll
            animating = true;
            finalPos = pos;
            event.preventDefault();
            clearTimeout(timeoutID);
            timeoutID = setTimeout(function() {
                console.log('scroll to ' + finalPos);
                window.scrollTo(window.scrollX, window.scrollY + finalPos);
                document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].style.transform = 'translateY(' + window.pageYOffset + 'px' + ')';
                setTimeout(function() {
                    animating = false;
                }, 100);
            }, 150);
        }
    }
}

if (window.addEventListener) {
    if ('onwheel' in document) {
        window.addEventListener("wheel", onWheel, {passive: false, capture: true}); // IE9+, FF17+, Ch31+
    } else if ('onmousewheel' in document) {
        window.addEventListener("mousewheel", onWheel); // устаревший вариант события
    } else {
        window.addEventListener("MozMousePixelScroll", onWheel); // Firefox < 17
    }
} else {
    window.attachEvent("onmousewheel", onWheel); // IE8-
}
```

Посмотреть работающий код можно [тут в jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lk46xw58/1/) или [тут на странице тестового сайта](http://test.kagg.eu/so/622338.html).

Comment: Я конечно могу ошибаться, но фиддл ссылается на фиддл автора. А на тестовой странице скролл неистово "лагает", видимо из-за слишком большого времени ожидания.

Comment: момент, спасибо. Исправил.

Comment: А теперь на тестовой странице, если для скролла пользоваться `mmb`, или `pageUp/pageDown`, или `пробел`, то событие не вызывается, квадрат стоит на месте.

Comment: Как раз наоборот - квадрат при pageUp/pageDown улетает. Потому что мой код перехватывает только onWheel.

Comment: Ну, относительно `body` он стоит на месте, да, а относительно вьюпорта - движется. Но, как мне кажется, это не совсем то поведение, которое ожидает автор, при скроллинге страницы не колесом. Кроме того, на гифке - автор тянет страницу за ползунок на скролле, `div` при этом, остается зафиксированным сверху вьюпорта. В вашем варианте, он остается вверху `body`, а не вьюпорта.

Comment: пусть автор сам уточнит, чего он хочет. Я же указал на фундаментальную проблему с событием scroll.

Comment: Ваш код впечатляет своей структурой, но это не совсем то что я хотел. Мне нужно было убрать скачки не колёсиком, а в общем, что бы при передвижении ползунка, верчения колёсиком, нажатия пробела и прочего в анимации не наблюдалось никаких скачков.

Comment: Вам придется перехватывать все события, приводящие к скроллу (я показал только на примере колеса) и писать аналогичные обработчики. Никак иначе.

Comment: Суть моего ответа не в том, чтобы дать полный код на все случаи жизни, а показать непростой путь, по которому придется пройти. Потому что системный скролл нельзя отменить. А кто обещал, что будет легко? ))

Comment: Опять же - вопрос в том, чего вы хотите добиться. Вот пример анимации по событию onscroll: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NNw9f_eauSk