# Как уменьшить скорость прокрутки страницы js?

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте.
такая проблема.есть вертикальный слайдер при прокрутки колесика мыши слайды меняются не плавно и не по одному

```
   //  запрашиваем DOM
  var links = document.querySelectorAll(".itemLinks");
  var wrapper = document.querySelector("#wrapper");

 // activeLink обеспечивает метку для активного элемента
 var activeLink = 0;

// устанавливаем отслеживание событий
for ( var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
var link = links[i] ;
link.addEventListener('click', setClickedItem, false);

// определяем элемент для activeLink
link.itemID = i;
}

// устанавливаем первый элемент в качестве активного
links[activeLink].classList.add("active");

function setClickedItem(e) {
    removeActiveLinks();

    var clickedLink = e.target;
    activeLink = clickedLink.itemID;

    changePosition(clickedLink);
}

function removeActiveLinks() {
    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        links[i].classList.remove("active");
    }
}

// Обработчик изменяет позицию слайдера, после того, как мы убедились,
// что в качестве активной обозначена нужная нам ссылка.
function changePosition(link) {
    link.classList.add("active");

    var position = link.getAttribute("data-pos");
    wrapper.style.top = position;
}
// добавляем действие кнопки "just say hi"
hi.onclick = function goTo() {

    removeActiveLinks();

    if (activeLink < links.length - 5) {
        activeLink++;
    } else {
        activeLink = 4;
    }

    var newLink = links[activeLink];
    changePosition(newLink);
  }
    // отслеживаем колесико мыши
 window.onload = function() {
 if (window.addEventListener) window.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll",
 mouse_wheel, false);
 window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = mouse_wheel;
 }
 var mouse_wheel = function(event) {
    if (false == !!event) event = window.event;
    var direction = ((event.wheelDelta) ? event.wheelDelta/120 : 
    event.detail/-3) || false;
}

// добавляем действие колесико мыши
window.onwheel = function(){
    removeActiveLinks();

    if (activeLink < links.length - 1) {
        activeLink++;
    } else {
        activeLink = 0;
    }
    var linkNew = links[activeLink];
    changePosition(linkNew);

   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том, что за время поворота колеса мыши вылетает 5-12 событий onwheel. Пока вы пытаетесь обработать первое, остальные пропадают. Вот [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/622338/%D0%9F%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-scroll%D0%B5/622563#622563) на StackOverflow я отвечал на похожий вопрос относительно скролла, с примером кода,который накапливает события onwheel.

Answer (score 0):

Во первых как я понял этот код

```
// отслеживаем колесико мыши
 window.onload = function() {
    if (window.addEventListener) window.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", mouse_wheel, false);
    window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = mouse_wheel;
}
var mouse_wheel = function(event) {
    if (false == !!event) event = window.event;
    var direction = ((event.wheelDelta) ? event.wheelDelta/120 : event.detail/-3) || false;
}
```

Можно просто удалить. Используйте стандартное событие `wheel`, что собственно вы и делаете в последней функции. Однако вместо того, чтобы опираться на частоту генерации событий, Вам надо учитывать насколько было прокручено колесико, то есть надо использовать свойство события WheelEvent, примерно так

```
var step = 200;
var currentScroll = 0;
window.onwheel = function(e) {
    currentScroll += e.deltaY;
    if (Math.abs(currentScroll) > step) {
        // действия по уменьшению currentScroll на step
        // и прокрутка слайдера в ту или иную сторону
    }
}
```

Увеличивая или уменьшая шаг, Вы сможете регулировать скорость прокрутки своего слайдера.

Подробнее о событии WheelEvent читайте здесь https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WheelEvent

Comment: спасибо за ответ.                                                                                      не совсем понятно ** // действия по уменьшению currentScroll на step**

Comment: Надо `currentScroll = Math.abs(currentScroll) - step` хотя там надо еще учитывать что currentScroll может быть отрицательный, тогда надо еще домножить на -1. То есть если начинаем крутить, надо предварительно обновить накопленное значение.