# Тяжелая JavaScript анимация (parallax)

Tags: javascript, анимация, parallax

Учу JS. Попробовал написать свой [Parallax](https://greezlu.github.io/parallax/Parallax.js) плагин. Сравнил его нагрузку на ЦП с [Parallax.js](https://github.com/wagerfield/parallax) в диспетчере задач Chrome. Мой оказался в разы тяжелее. Ниже я опишу логику которой руководствовался. Как должно быть я понять не смог.

Вопроса два: Почему такая разница? И как должно быть?

Есть массив с объектами, которые нужно двигать. Каждое движение мыши рассчитывает новое положение для каждого объекта (через `for(){}`) и отправляет на отрисовку через:
`requestId = requestAnimationFrame(animate)`

Функция `animate` пробегается по отдельному массиву с новыми координатами

(через `for(){}`) и отрисовывает движение.

Каждый новый запрос на отрисовку сопровождается отменой предыдущего:
`cancelAnimationFrame(requestId)`

Посмотреть на функцию в работе можно [здесь](https://greezlu.github.io/html/parallax/snk/) (2.3Mb)

Comment: Обычно во всех обработчиках скролла и перемещений делают буферизацию событий. То есть в течение некоторого времени накапливают события, а потом их разом отрабатывают. Нечто подобное я писал в своем ответе о "дерганном" скролле: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/622563/220220    У вас буферизации событий, похоже, нет. Полагаю, что это и является причиной большой нагрузки на процессор.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На сколько я посмотрел вы меняйте положение элементов через изменение значений, left и top.

Когда вы изменяете набор значений для шести свойств CSS: margin, padding, top, left, bottom или right, браузер выполняет дополнительные вычисления того, как это отобразится на макете всей страницы. Поэтому для увеличения производительности анимации лучше использовать:

```
.foo {
   transform: translate3d(x, y, z); 
}
```

Причина, по которой transform является более производительным, заключается в том, что оно не затрагивают никакие другие элементы. Любые действия, которые вы выполняете, применяются только к одному элементу, и браузеру не нужно перестраивать все окно. Он модифицирует только ту часть экрана, которая содержит перемещающийся контент.

Так же при преобразовании элемента с помощью translate3d он обрабатывается через GPU в Webkit-браузерах, таких как Chrome и Safari (которые установлены на iPhone и iPad), в Internet Explorer 9/10, а также в последних версиях Firefox.

Поэтому при использовании translate3d вы получаете преимущества локальной перестройки экрана. Но кроме этого, вы получаете дополнительные преимущества, так как вся работа выполняется GPU.

Comment: Спасибо, думаю это поможет. Parallax.js использует как раз translate3d, но я не думал что оно может так сильно влиять на производительность. Печально, но отличий почти не будет.