# Параллаксный фон неплавно прокручивается

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, wordpress, css3

Есть сайт chanceoflife.ru, на нем для главной страницы и раздела контактов задан фон с реализованной через js параллаксной прокруткой фона секции. На компьютерах она работает нормально (плавно), а на телефонах (iPhone 6 в частности) она тормозит (двигается рывками).

Судя по периодичности срабатывания обработчика scroll, на мобильных браузерах он вызывается реже, чем на компьютерных.

Есть ли возможность реализовать это как-то по-другому (в идеале - чистым css3)? Страницы созданы в конструкторе Elementor, посему менять верстку очень не хотелось бы.

Код:

```js
    function setOffset($parallaxBlock,yPos,yPosOld) {
        var yPosNew = -($parallaxBlock.offset().top - $window.scrollTop())/divider; //считаем смещение
        var coords = 'center '+ yPos + 'px';
        $parallaxBlock.css('background-position', coords); //устанавливаем смещение         
    }

    $('.parallax,section.elementor-top-section').each(function() { //выполняем скрипт отдельно для каждой секции 
        if(!$(this).css('background-image'))return;
        var $parallaxBlock = $(this); 
        var parallaxFunc = async function(event) { 
            if (forceParallax || $window.width() >= 720) { //если ширина окна >= 720 или параллакс обязателен 
                var offset = $parallaxBlock.offset().top; //расстояние от начала документа до секции 
                var scrollTop = $window.scrollTop(); //прокрученное расстояние 
                var yPos = -(offset - scrollTop)/(divider); //считаем смещение 
                setOffset($parallaxBlock,yPos,yPosOld);
                console.log('Parallax ',event.data.type,' on ',scrollTop,'/',yPos,'(was ',yPosOld,')',' units');
                yPosOld=yPos;
            } else { 
                $parallaxBlock.css('background-position', 'center'); //если нет - отключаем
            } 
        }; 
        parallaxFunc({data:{type:"load"}}); //выполняем нашу функцию при загрузке страницы 
        $window.on('scroll',null,{type:"scroll"}, parallaxFunc); //и при прокрутке 
        $window.on('resize',{type:"resize"}, parallaxFunc); //и при растяге
    });
```

Comment: Дело как раз в обратном. Обработчик scroll вызывается слишком часто, и на мобилках процессор не справляется. Вы поставьте console.log в ваш обрпботчик и увидите, что на каждое прикосновение к колесу мыши он вызывается по 5-10 раз.

Comment: Чтобы работало плавно, в обработчик ставят таймаут на 100-300мс, каждый раз при получении события scroll. И только тогда, когда пачка событий scroll закончится, делают основную работу обработчика.

Comment: console.log там стоит (по нему и данные брал). Код обновил.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/622563/220220